# invalid syntax in sklearn.feature_extraction.text

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to apply k-Means clustering on a text.I have installed sklearn packages but still finding error in it...I am facing a problem in this code below right now...it says invalid syntax on line 1 (sklearn.feature_extraction.text)

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text 
import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster 
import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics 
import adjusted_rand_score

documents = ["This little kitty came to play when I was eating at a restaurant.",
             "Merley has the best squooshy kitten belly.",
             "Google Translate app is incredible.",
             "If you open 100 tab in google you get a smiley face.",
             "Best cat photo I've ever taken.",
             "Climbing ninja cat.",
             "Impressed with google map feedback.",
             "Key promoter extension for Google Chrome."]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)

true_k = 2
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1)
model.fit(X)

print("Top terms per cluster:")
order_centroids = model.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
for i in range(true_k):
    print("Cluster %d:" % i),
    for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
        print(' %s' % terms[ind]),
    print

print("\n")
print("Prediction")

Y = vectorizer.transform(["chrome browser to open."])
prediction = model.predict(Y)
print(prediction)

Y = vectorizer.transform(["My cat is hungry."])
prediction = model.predict(Y)
print(prediction)
```

Problem is
{
    "message": "invalid syntax (, line 1)",

}

Answer (score 1):

I think your imports are off syntactically, the `from...import` needs to be on one line.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import adjusted_rand_score
```

Comment: Previous problem is solved but still I am having this problem:

Comment: I am having another problem in same code:ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
PS C:\Users\Dell> & C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python.exe f:/ERD/Kmeans.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:/ERD/Kmeans.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from .utils._show_versions import show_versions